# "Не+приемлемо". Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, грамматика

В сочетании "технически не+приемлемо" *не* — отдельно?

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта возможны, с некоторой разницей в значении.
В обычном смысле скорее - слитно.
Правда, смысл-то мне и не очень понятен, как ни напиши.
Я понимаю "технически нереализуемо", "технически невозможно" и "политически неприемлемо". Или, например, "экономически нецелесообразно". 
А что такое "технически неприемлемо"?